# Show properties in view from derived classes

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get my head around inheritance and polymorphism and run into maybe a simple problem.

I got an abstract base class and two derived classes. I created a viewmodel containing a list with type of the base class, which I pass to the view.

My question is how can I show the properties of the derived classes in the view?

Models

```
public abstract class Card
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Manacost { get; set; }
}

public class Spell : Card
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Minion: Card
{
    public int AttackPower { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel passed to view

```
public class DeckbuilderVM
{
    public List<Card> CardLibary { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model.DeckbuilderVM

@foreach (var item in Model.CardLibary)
{
    //Can acces these
    <p>Name: @item.Name</p>
    <p>Manacost: @item.Manacost</p> 

    //Can't acces these
    <p>Attactpower: @item.AttackPower </p>
    <p>Health: @item.Health </p>

//How to acces property of the derived classes?
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you can do what you are asking (without using reflection). The point in OOP of using a base class type instead of derived type is that you are saying you _don't_ want the things specific to each derived type. In your example, inheritance is used just to reuse implementation, and there's no polymorphism. It's also odd (and wrong) for a class to be marked `abstract` when it has no `abstract` members.

Comment: `//How to acces property of the derived classes?` => You need to cast them in child class in order to use it. or at least need a reference of the child class to access those properties.

Comment: @Peter I could see a compelling case for an abstract class if the real word object you are modeling is always an abstraction of specific types.

Comment: @NickBailey: well, it's just my opinion. I'd add "IMO", but the comment is too old. Even if you never intend the class to be instantiated, I don't see the point in marking it `abstract`, but obviously opinions vary. :)

Comment: well the point with abstract was It shoulden't be posiible to create a object of card but only of the derived classes. Basicly i just want all my objects in one list so I could iterate over all at once no matter which derived class they are from. Is that a wrong approch of thinking?